# Why "flag" a question when I have access to "close"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281769/674675):

> **If you have the privilege to cast close votes**, it doesn't matter at all if you do it via the 'close' link or via the 'flag' link and
>   the option 'Should be closed ...'. It will count as a close vote, not
>   a flag. The 'close' link is just a 'shortcut' for an action which is
>   quite often necessary.
>
> **If you don't have the privilege**, then you don't see the close link at all. Flag -> 'Should be closed ...' will count as a flag, not a
>   close vote.

Recently I got access to the `close` link and I still have access to the `flag` link. It makes me befuddled to choose which one if I find a problematic question. I think the SE should remove "flag" for users that reached +3k reputations.

Why should I flag it if I have access to vote to close a question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why should I flag it if I have access to vote to close a question?

There are still (not close worthy) reasons that you can only flag which don't appear in the close dialog, like e.g. *spam*, *rude or abusive*.

These will be handled differently apart the common closure reasonings, e.g. involving the whole community into the process of deleting posts, or giving special attention to site moderators in their working queues.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It's an indeed answer but I wait for others if they'll get me some more information. I think the SE should remove "flag" for users that reached +3k reputations.

Comment: @M.Rostami Spam and Rude/Abusive posts should still be flagged rather than closed regardless of your rep.

Comment: @M.Rostami _"but I wait for others if they'll get me some more information"_ Well, your question is closed now as a duplicate. But I can still edit my answer to give you more information if necessary. Or you can edit your question to explain why the answers in the duplicate don't satisfy what you've been asking for.

Comment: *I think the SE should remove "flag" for users that reached +3k reputations.* one could argue that the 'close' option should be removed from that dialog. That's a [tag:feature-request] and I swear I've seen it before, but can't find it right now. It's not really beneficial IMHO; it *takes away* options from a user. If I misclick because I forgot I can actually vote to close on a particular site, I don't want to open a new dialog.